# JQuery: How to get name of a select when value is known?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I need to get the name of a select (#Dropdown) when its value is known but can't seem to get the syntax right. Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var countrycode = '55';
   var name = $("#Dropdown[value=countrycode]").text();  // fails here
   if(name == 'Germany')
   {..... etc
```

I can get it to work as follows in a different context when I'm able to use "this":

```
var name = $(this[value=countrycode]).text();
```

... but that's not available in the first example.

Anyone? Thanks.

Comment: a select's value isn't defined until something is selected ----
see Adam Kiss' + Benoit's response for the answer ----

i.e., your #Dropdown is unique so just use: 

    var name = $("#Dropdown").attr("name");

Comment: @davidosomething... yep, it's a more complicated scenario, form submission where the select options were originally generated via Ajax, so I now want to repopulate them for the user for a smoother experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look for the option value within the select.

```
var countrycode = '55';
var name = $("#Dropdown option[value="+countrycode+"]").text();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're including "countrycode" literally in your selector string.

There's probably a better way to do it, but this should work:

```
var name = $("#Dropdown[value=" + countrycode + "]").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Post also HTML, it seems kind of wrong - you can have just one ID (#something) per page, so there would be no need for something like `#id[value=*]`.

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't normally be needed, but it's a repopulation of $_POST select options (when form submission failed validation) for dynamic selects that were populated with Ajax on first load, so the page can't remember them. The countrycode I pass to JQuery via PHP.

Comment: well its either something like `$('select[value=*]')` -> tag[value] OR `$(#id)` -> id :] - it does not make sense at all to use both, needless to say in this combination.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but I think you've misunderstood the question. Imagine #Dropdown as a unique select on the page.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var name = $("#Dropdown option[value=" + countrycode + "]").text()
```